# How to build this caluculated columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to get a dataframe that shows me, in correspondence with the warehouse loads, when the stock would run out (excluding subsequent loads)

The starting dataframe is this:
[starting dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8mAr.png)

Here you have the code to build it:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'warehouse': ['M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M2'],
        'item': ['Partxy', 'Partxy', 'Partxy', 'Partxy', 'Partxy', 'Partxy', 'Partxy', 'Partxy', 'Partxy', 'Partz'],
        'date': ['01/01/2023', '05/01/2023', '07/01/2023', '08/01/2023', '09/01/2023', '10/01/2023', '15/01/2023', '18/01/2023', '19/01/2023', '22/01/2023'],
        'tot_load_replenishment': [0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 50, 0, 50, 0, 0],
        'tot_unload': [0, -30, -15, -50, -10, -5, -30, -10, -5, -10],
        'stock': [100, 70, 75, 25, 15, 60, 30, 70, 65, 300],
        'stock_before_load': [None, None, 55, None, None, 10, None, 20, None, None]}


load_unload = pd.DataFrame(data)

load_unload['tot_load_replenishment'] = load_unload['tot_load_replenishment'].astype(int)
load_unload['tot_unload'] = load_unload['tot_unload'].astype(int)
load_unload['date'] = pd.to_datetime(load_unload['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

What I want to obtain is this:

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsySF.png)

I tried this code:

```
#pass one item in one warehouse
item = 'Partxy'
warehouse = 'M1'

#filter the dataframe
item_war = (load_unload['item'] == item) & (load_unload['warehouse'] == warehouse) 
load_unload_item_war = load_unload[item_war]

#consider only the row where I have some load for replenishment
mov_replenishment = load_unload_item_war[load_unload_item_war['tot_load_replenishment'] > 0]

#define a function that return the exhaustion_date, given the stock_before_load
def exhaustion_date(row, load_unload_item_war):

    #consider only lines from today forward
    f_load_unload_item_war = load_unload_item_war[(load_unload_item_war['date'] > row['date'])]
    
    #store the stock before load in a specific variable
    residual = row['stock_before_load']
    
    #calculate the cumulative unloaded
    f_load_unload_item_war['cum_unload'] = f_load_unload_item_war['tot_unload'].cumsum()*(-1)
    
    #filter the dataframe to find the first date in which stock would become negative
    exhaustion_date = f_load_unload_item_war.loc[f_load_unload_item_war['tot_unload'] < residual, 'date'].min()
    
    return exhaustion_date

#apply the function to obtain the exaustion date only when I have a replenishment
mov_replenishment['exhaustion_date'] = mov_replenishment.apply(lambda row: exhaustion_date(row, load_unload_item_war), axis=1)
```

What I obtain is this (not correct):

[final result not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpcIx.png)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me!

Comment: Please show us the code you tried.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please consider visiting [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we may better assist you.

Comment: Please provide more detail and the code you've written.  We're here to help but you have to do your part. What did you try and what error are you getting?

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Comment: I edit my comment to be more clear